# AJAX/FLASK/JS: How to POST existing array into endpoint?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, flask, post

I am trying to POST the **songFiles** array pushed from the **getTableData()** function (inside the ajax request) into the **/api/fileNames** endpoint, which is then sent to a callback **postFileNames()** that should post the array, but I just can't seem to get it working. Any help would be appreciated, including maybe other ways to do this.

*I'm a bit of beginner with using ajax and flask, I have scoured far and wide for a solution, but can't seem to find any to fit my goal, forgive my lack of knowledge.*

**JavaScript Code**

```
function getTableData() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/getSong",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            createMusicTable();
            
            let indexObj = Object.keys(data.song).length;
            
            for (var i = 0; i < indexObj; i++) {
                var song = data.song[i]
                var id = data.song[i].song_id;
                var fileName = data.song[i].song_file + ".mp3";
                
                songFiles.push(fileName);
                appendMusic(song, id);
                
                songTitle.id = "s" + i;
                console.log("td-ok");
            }
            postFileNames(songFiles);
        }
    });
}
function postFileNames(data) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/fileNames",
        dataType: "json", // data is an array, so not sure what to put here. 
        data: data, // not sure if correct
        success: function(data) {
            // should: post the data into the endpoint.
            // data is not logged, goes straight to error.
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("cry")
        }
    })
}
```

**FLASK Endpoint Code**

```
@app.route("/api/fileNames", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def fileNameStorage():
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.get_data() # not too sure what to do here either.
    return data 
else:
    return "error" # currently goes to 'return error'
```

Comment: `postFileNames(songFiles);` ---> May be try moving this line outside the `for` loop? Right now, each time an element is added to `songFiles` the method is called - which is redundant, I think.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. Totally overlooked that, thanks. I've changed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.route("/api/fileNames", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def fileNameStorage():
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = {
    "id": request.json["id"],
    "song_name": request.json["song_name"],
    "time_duration": request.json["time_duration"]
}
    return data, 200
else:
    return "error", 400 # currently goes to 'return error'
```

Would be more prettier if you would :

```
@app.route("/songs/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def songs():
  return Songs().get_songs(), 200
```

In routes.py file
and the other classes and methods in another file

Maybe try jsonify(array) or json.dump(array) if it's a problem to map the array elements.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for taking the time to help.
Just one question, where would I jsonify/dump the array? Within the app.flask or in the ajax request? Thanks!

Comment: On flask side, add the following code the the handler function
```
import json
data = json.dump(array)
print(data)
```
This would allow you to make sure the array data is valid

Comment: Okay, amazing! And sorry but I have one more question. How should I declare the (array) because currently it has no value inside flask? Again, thank you.

Comment: It could be caused from front,

const data = { "operation" : operation, "song": song};
fetch('/wifi/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                throw response;
            })
This is the code I'm using on frontend side, take a look on headers and body.
The array should be posted in JSON format.

Comment: Alright, I will. Well thank you so much, I will accept this as an answer. Think I've got all the info I need. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: GOT IT WORKING! Spent the whole day trying to get it to work. tysm.